# My acer tree looks unhealthy/is dying - Pls help!

Tags: maple

I have a beautiful Acer tree which was re-potted about 2 years ago. The only reason me and my dad re-potted it was because the existing pot was in its last days. There was no bottom anymore and the sides started to corrode and I just thought this was the chance to do it. The pot was metallic.

The new pot is 'wooden' on the outside and I think inside the lining is plastic. It is bigger in diameter but height wise was probably the same as the old one. Maybe a tiny bit shorter.

Since the repotting, I feel like the tree hasn't flourished or gone back to its old self. This year in particular a lot of the leaves have already shrivelled, or are half red half brown.

Its location hasn't changed and the place where it is, it is quite sheltered.

I have touched a couple of areas with a sharp object and I don't think the branches seem dead.

I have bought Vitax Japanese Maple Acer feed two weeks ago and sprinkled some on top. I also put some Miracle Gro All purpose compost at the top of the pot to see if that makes any difference whatsoever.

I am attaching lots of photos. Let me know if there's something obvious or something I should to salvage this beautiful tree.

I can't attach more than 8 photos.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Judging by the pictures, you have been slowly killing it for a long time by keeping it in a pot that is about 10 times too small for it.

Comment: Can you help with dimensions of a pot that would be suitable? Also is it too late to salvage if I repot?

Comment: Also should I do this now or wait until September? I am in London

Comment: @alephzero Would Greatly appreciate any feedback/response